# Why aren't the 2 components exactly above each other when margin is same?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm very new (Day 1) to Android programming so I might be missing something very obvious.

[image]

In this, why is "Weight" TextView and it's EditText component not exactly above each other? Same goes for the NumberPicker and "Reps" TextView. From what I understand, as width is same for both components and margin is same too, they should be exactly above each other.

XML for reference:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    tools:context="host.abhi.rmcalc.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/noRepsHeading"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Reps"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/noReps"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/enteredWeightHeading"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enteredWeight"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="107dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="false"
        android:fontFamily="@font/archivo_black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="00"
        android:inputType="textPersonName|numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/oneRepMax"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/noReps"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/enteredWeightHeading"
        tools:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/oneRepMax"
        android:layout_width="391dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:fontFamily="@font/archivo_black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="100sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/oneRepMaxHeading" />

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/noReps"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="109dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="78dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/oneRepMax"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/enteredWeight"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/noRepsHeading" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/enteredWeightHeading"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Weight"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/enteredWeight"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/noRepsHeading"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/oneRepMaxHeading"
        android:layout_width="283dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1RM Estimated"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry but didnt understand the term "above each other"

Comment: "Weight" TextView's center is not inline with the center of EditText below. @WebInsight

Comment: app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/enteredWeightHeading" in the 1st edittext is wrong. Both should be top not top and bottom

Comment: @WebInsight Thanks for replying. However, it's not clear as to what exactly would fix it.

Comment: The problem is that you are aligning the top of the 1st edittext with the bottom of the 1st textview. It is behaving exactly as is written. Try to align the top of the 1st edittext with the bottom of the 1st textview

Comment: @AbhijeetRastogi Did the answer I have posted help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the culprit right here

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/enteredWeightHeading"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Weight"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/enteredWeight"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/noRepsHeading"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside" <!--PROBLEM HERE-->
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

The simplest explanation is that there are 3 `chainStyles`

- **Packed** - The elements in the chain are place as close to each other as possible, with any remaining space pushed towards the margins.
- **Spread_inside** - The first 2 elements are placed starting and ending at the margins and any remaining space or widgets are distributed evenly between the first 2 elements.
- **Spread** *(Default)* - All the widgets and any remaining space is distributed evenly in the view.

To fix the problem just change the `chainStyle` to `spread`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/enteredWeightHeading"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Weight"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/enteredWeight"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/noRepsHeading"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Hope this helps!

**Edit**

From the [documentaion](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constrain-chain)

> - Spread: The views are evenly distributed (after margins are accounted for). This is the default.
> - Spread inside: The first and last view are affixed to the constraints on each end of the chain and the rest are evenly distributed.
> - Weighted: When the chain is set to either spread or spread inside, you can fill the remaining space by setting one or more views to "match constraints" (0dp). By default, the space is evenly distributed between each view that's set to "match constraints," but you can assign a weight of importance to each view using the layout_constraintHorizontal_weight and layout_constraintVertical_weight attributes. If you're familiar with layout_weight in a linear layout, this works the same way. So the view with the highest weight value gets the most amount of space; views that have the same weight get the same amount of space.
> - Packed: The views are packed together (after margins are accounted for). You can then adjust the whole chain's bias (left/right or up/down) by changing the chain's head view bias.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. @Ajil.